# I found a puzzle that no-one can solve

Tags: riddle, knowledge, history

I found a puzzle that no-one can solve.

I created a law but I was not a lawyer.

I lived in a hostile world but found refuge in a hut.

---

Who was I, and can you explain my story?

Clue 1

> The word "created" is used loosely. I can be considered to have created the law as a result of the sum of my actions. The actual statute came posthumously.

Clue 2

> The 'puzzle' was a puzzle to me and I was able to show that it was insoluble. Later someone described it as a *problem* instead of a puzzle. That person's terminology has stuck to this day. P.S. No person or intelligent life-form or computer can solve this problem universally.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie - rot13(Gur sbyybjvat cvpgher vf abg gur uhg va dhrfgvba ohg, rkpyhqvat gur cbepu, gur fglyr bs pbafgehpgvba vf irel fvzvyne. uggcf://jjj.qbp.tbig.am/tybonynffrgf/vzntrf/cynprf/pnagreohel/neguhef-cnff/pebj-uhg/pebj-uhg-jvqr-1200.wct )

Comment: Lawyers generally do not create laws

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft  - Fair point. I used that in part to eliminate Pierre Fermat who *was* a lawyer and yet owes all his fame to his mathematical discoveries.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are:

> [Alan Turing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing)!

---

I found a puzzle that no-one can solve.

> The [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) - where Alan Turing proved that a general algorithm to solve the halting problem for all possible program-input pairs cannot exist.

I created a law but I was not a lawyer.

> [The Alan Turing Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing_law) named after Alan Turing who was not a lawyer. This was named in 2013, posthumously.

I lived in a hostile world but found refuge in a hut.

> Alan Turing was [convicted of public indecency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing#Conviction_for_indecency), after starting a relationship with a man which was illegal at the time. The world was also very hostile as there was WWII. [Hut 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hut_8) was a section at Bletchley Park, led by Alan Turing during WWII.

Comment: Well done! You have found me. However before accepting I must insist on the correct answer to your second point. I'll see what I can do in the clues to help. Neither of the things you suggest is insoluble.  P.S. You are right about the hostile world. Of course there was a lot of hostility going on at the time in the wider world as well!

Comment: @chaslyfromUK i assume you mean first point? I’ll do a bit more research

Comment: @chaslyfromUK would the problem be quite halting for an individual by any chance :P

Comment: Bingo!  ............

Answer (score 14):

Perhaps a long shot:

> Sir Isaac Newton

> I found a puzzle that no-one can solve.

> [This problem](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5161/did-newton-find-the-trajectory-of-a-body-moving-in-uniform-gravity-under-the-qua) (about the trajectory of a projectile) worked on by Newton does not seem to have a solution (I am no expert on this subject).

> I created a law but I was not a lawyer.

> Newton's law of universal gravitation

> I lived in a hostile world but found refuge in a hut.

> He found refuge in a [stone cottage](https://www.arborsci.com/blogs/cool/a-visit-to-isaac-newtons-home) during the plague.

Comment: A good try but a stone-cottage is not a hut!  Also note, this is a problem that ***no-one***   can solve. I'm not sure that applies to Newton's.  Note: "No-one" here is not wordplay. Literally no human being or alien creature can solve this.

Comment: ... or computer.  Perhaps an omniscient god could solve it but that's for theologians to debate!